# Is there a unix command line tool that can analyze font files?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, fonts

Given a directory of font files (TTF and OTF) I'd like to inspect each font and determine what style (regular, italic, bold, bold-italic) it is. Is there a command line tool for unix flavored operating systems that can do this? Or does anyone know how to extract the metadata from a TTF or OTF font file?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think you're looking for [otfinfo](http://www.lcdf.org/type/#typetools).  There doesn't seem to be [an option](http://www.lcdf.org/type/otfinfo.1.html) to get at the Subfamily directly, but you could do:

```
otfinfo --info *.ttf | grep Subfamily
```

Note that a number of the fonts I looked at use "Oblique" instead of "Italic".

Comment: Perfect, thanks! For those interested I'm on OS X and installed it via brew with `brew install lcdf-typetools`

Comment: FWIW, the MacPorts package is also called `lcdf-typetools` (and is a dependency of `texlive-fontutils`, so it may already be installed for people using TeX).

Comment: The nix package is called `nixpkgs.lcdf-typetools`

Comment: On Fedora 37 it's called `texlive-lcdftypetools`

Answer (score 31):

In Linux, if you have .ttf fonts, you most probably also have [fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/), which comes with the `fc-scan` utility. You can parse the output for the information you want, or use the badly documented `--format` option.

For example:

```bash
fc-scan --format "%{foundry} : %{family}\n" /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbd.ttf
```

The font properties you can print this way are shown here: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html#AEN21

Some properties are listed in multiple languages. For example, `%{fullname}` may be a list. In that case, `%{fullnamelang}` will list the languages. If that shows you your language in fourth position in the list, you can use `%{fullname[3]}` as the format string to print the full name in only that language.

This language stuff being quite inconvenient, I ended up writing a full Perl script to list the info I wanted in only one language:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $VERSION = 0.1;
my $debug = 1;

my @wanted = qw(foundry family fullname style weight slant width spacing file);
my @lang_dependent = qw(family fullname style);
my $lang = "en";

my $separator = ", ";


use File::Basename;
use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;


my $me = basename $0;
die "Usage: $me FILENAME\n" unless @ARGV;

my $fontfile = shift;

unless (-f $fontfile) {
    die "Bad argument: '$fontfile' is not a file !\n";
}


my $fc_format = join( "\\n", map { "\%{$_}" } @wanted );

my @info = `fc-scan --format "$fc_format" "$fontfile"`;
chomp @info;

my %fontinfo;
@fontinfo{@wanted} = @info;

if ( grep /,/, @fontinfo{ @lang_dependent } ) {
    my $format = join( "\\n", map { "\%{${_}lang}" } @lang_dependent );
    my @langs = `fc-scan --format "$format" "$fontfile"`;

    for my $i (0..$#lang_dependent) {
        my @lang_list = split /,/, $langs[$i];
        my ($pos) = grep { $lang_list[$_] ~~ $lang } 0 .. $#lang_list;
        my @vals = split /,/, $fontinfo{$lang_dependent[$i]};
        $fontinfo{$lang_dependent[$i]} = $vals[$pos];
    }
}

warn Dumper(\%fontinfo), "\n" if $debug;

$fontinfo{'fullname'} ||= $fontinfo{'family'}; # some old fonts don't have a fullname? (WINNT/Fonts/marlett.ttf)

print join($separator, @fontinfo{@wanted}), "\n";
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tip (and script.. though I haven't tested the script yet). Do you know if there's a way to get license/copyright info as well? I tried %{license}, %{copyright} and no format, but none of those yielded anything, whereas fontforge is able to show it to me.

Comment: Indeed, fc-scan does't seem to show the copyright. `foundry` is the closest it gives you. But `otfinfo -i`, suggested by cjm, does display it.

Comment: Ah that's great, I installed `lcdf-typetools` and and ran `otfinfo -i` as suggested and that did the trick, thanks! (And I gave @cjm a +1 as well).

Comment: fc-scan is great for getting the font "fullname" that is used to reference the font in programs.

Comment: If you want to avoid the language issue, `postscriptname` instead of `fullname` gives you the same information, language-independent, in a different format.

Alternatively, in bash: `for fontfile in /mnt/Fonts/*.{otf,ttf}; do fc-scan --format "%{fullname[$(( $(sed -E 's/^(.*)en.*/\1/;s/[^,]//g' <<< "$(fc-scan --format "%{fullnamelang}\n" ${fontfile})" | wc -c) -1 ))]}\n" "${fontfile}"; done > fontlist.txt`

Comment: @emk2203 That is money!

Comment: The notes on the --format option are priceless.