# How do I get the font name from a font file?

Tags: fonts

Say I have a file "foo_whatever.ttf"  Is there a command line tool to get the actual font name from the file?

---

The below link does contain the answer but I didn't turn it up in my search results, in particular "/fonts name".  Looking back, I could have used a more general search.  What is mod policy on this?

[Is there a unix command line tool that can analyze font files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26053/is-there-a-unix-command-line-tool-that-can-analyze-font-files)

This is in fact the link I found that led me to the correct answer (where I learned of the rest of the `fc-` commands:

[How to get the real name of font?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305931/how-to-get-the-real-name-of-font)

Comment: At the end of the file there could be copyright information that reveals the font type. Have you tried: strings <ttf file>?

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox I've thought about that too. The font name appears but it's probably hard to retrieve its exact position.

Comment: @dr01 Agreed, however isaac had a nice link to determine the font type.

Comment: @isaac that post does indeed have the correct info, however if I search for "/fonts name" it isn't even in the first page of results.

Comment: @mpr no worries, nobody's saying you should have found it ;-). But since it exists, we might as well link to it to avoid repeating information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `fc-scan` from the fontconfig package:

```
[root@centos7 ~]# fc-scan /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf 
Pattern has 22 elts (size 32)
    family: "Liberation Serif"(s)
    familylang: "en"(s)
    style: "Regular"(s)
    stylelang: "en"(s)
    fullname: "Liberation Serif"(s)
    fullnamelang: "en"(s)
    slant: 0(i)(s)
    weight: 80(i)(s)
    width: 100(i)(s)
    foundry: "unknown"(s)
    file: "/usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf"(s)
    index: 0(i)(s)
    outline: True(s)
    scalable: True(s)
    charset: 
    0000: 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff 7fffffff 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0001: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 00040000 00000000 00000000 fc000000
    0002: 0f000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 3f0002c0 00000000
    0003: 00000000 00000000 00000000 40000000 ffffd7f0 fffffffb 00007fff 00000000
    0004: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 00000000 00030000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    001e: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000003f 00000000 00000000 000c0000
    0020: 7fbb0000 560d0047 00000010 80000000 00000000 00001098 00000000 00000000
    0021: 00480020 00004044 78000000 00000000 003f0000 00000100 00000000 00000000
    0022: c6268044 00000a00 00000100 00000033 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0023: 00010004 00000003 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0025: 11111005 10101010 ffff0000 00001fff 000f1111 14041c03 03008c10 00000040
    0026: 00000000 1c000000 00000005 00000c69 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    00f0: 00000036 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    00fb: 00000006 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
(s)
    lang: aa|af|av|ay|be|bg|bi|br|bs|ca|ce|ch|co|cs|cy|da|de|el|en|eo|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fo|fr|fur|fy|gd|gl|gv|ho|hr|hu|ia|id|ie|ik|io|is|it|ki|kl|kum|la|lb|lez|lt|lv|mg|mh|mk|mo|mt|nb|nds|nl|nn|no|nr|nso|ny|oc|om|os|pl|pt|rm|ro|ru|se|sel|sk|sl|sma|smj|smn|so|sq|sr|ss|st|sv|sw|tk|tl|tn|tr|ts|uk|uz|vo|vot|wa|wen|wo|xh|yap|zu|an|crh|csb|fil|hsb|ht|jv|kj|ku-tr|kwm|lg|li|ms|na|ng|pap-an|pap-aw|rn|rw|sc|sg|sn|su|za(s)
    fontversion: 70123(i)(s)
    capability: "otlayout:DFLT otlayout:cyrl otlayout:grek otlayout:latn"(s)
    fontformat: "TrueType"(s)
    decorative: False(s)
    hash: "sha256:2829b7333ab4697f7b2d68855fca83f1be92121db16dd0bfcf3ae2b416839b05"(s)
    postscriptname: "LiberationSerif"(s)
```

After which, you can grep from its output for `fullname` or `postscriptname`:

```bash
fc-scan <font-name> | grep fullname
```